# background-image: url("images/plaid.jpg") no-repeat; wont show up

Tags: jquery, css, background, stylesheet

I can't seem to make my plaid.jpg the background on any of my pages, let alone all of them, I've tried selecting it by body, html, *, the specific id of "home". nothing works. The image is 300 x 421 pixels. I don't need it to show up pretty, i just want it to show up, behind everything. how would my css look for this? the plaid.jpg picture is in my images folder in the same directory as my index.html file. This link is at the top of my index.html file. and my stylesheet is in my stylesheets folder named mystyles.css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/mystyles.css">
```

I have tried altering my .CSS file every way imaginable in my opinion. the first 30 google results for "background-image not showing up" and none worked. I'm aware it's probably something simple.

mystyles.css in its most basic form with no selector.

```
  background-image: url("images/plaid.jpg") no-repeat;
```

index.html

```
 <body>
        <!-- Page: home -->
            <div id="home"
                data-role="page"
                data-title="Home">
                <div data-role="header"
                    data-position="fixed"
                    data-theme="b">
                    <h1>Home</h1>
                    <a href="#info"
                        data-icon="info"
                        data-iconpos="notext"
                        data-rel="dialog"
                        class="ui-btn-right"
                        >Info</a>
                </div><!-- header -->
                <div data-role="content">

                <div data-role="controlgroup" data-theme="e">
                    <a href="#blog" 
                        data-role="button"
                        data-icon="arrow-r"
                         data-theme="e"
                    >Blog</a>
                    <a href="#videos" 
                        data-role="button"
                        data-icon="arrow-r"
                         data-theme="e"
                    >Videos</a>
                    <a href="#photos" 
                        data-role="button"
                        data-icon="arrow-r"
                         data-theme="e"
                    >Photos</a>
                    <a href="#tweets" 
                        data-role="button"
                        data-icon="arrow-r"
                         data-theme="e"
                    >Tweets</a>
                </div><!-- links -->
                </div> <!-- content -->
            </div><!-- page -->
```

this wasn't succesful

```
body {
    background-image: url("/images/plaid.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

this is whats in my  also

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Mob App</title>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" /> 

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <script src="javascripts/myscript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/mystyles.css" />
    </head>
```

Comment: Anything in the browser console?

Comment: If your CSS isn't working, check to make sure your HTML *and* CSS is valid.

Comment: no errors in console. and when i view source it sees my .css file so its linked correctly.

Comment: @codeyb Checking the console isn't the same as validation.

Comment: You know what would be funny?  If the background image *is* loading, but you can't see it because the `body` has completely collapsed because all of its children are floating (without a clearfix) or absolutely positioned.  Everything matters.  Cut away all details that don't look like they're part of the problem until you find it.  That's how you debug things.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, this is all thats left on the website, I dont have any other objects on the page, and theres only 1 css selector in my css file. I've stripped it down to everything in the post is whats on my website.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You either use :

```
background-image: url("images/plaid.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

... or

```
background: transparent url("images/plaid.jpg") top left no-repeat;
```

... but definitively **not**

```
background-image: url("images/plaid.jpg") no-repeat;
```

**EDIT** : Demo at **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gfWES/)** using absolute paths (in case you have troubles referring to your images with relative paths).

Comment: `background-color` and `background-position` are completely optional (`transparent` and `top left` are the values for those properties if not specified)

Comment: @cimmanon : agree. I just wanted to illustrate the full shorthand property.

Comment: I gave them both a shot with no success. and another poster said not to use url("images/plaid.jpg") but rather url("/images/plaid.jpg") I tried those ways, amounting to 4 variations. I dont know what to believe though, my plaid.jpg file in in my images folder in the root directory, aka same place as my index.html, and my .css file is in my stylesheets folder in the same root directory. so its linked and sees the file, just refuses to obey the selector and style. i also tried putting the plaid.jpg file in the stylesheets folder and changing the path in the .css file

Comment: Make sure you know where exactly your images are, otherwise use absolute paths. **[SEE this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gfWES/)**

Comment: I used the absolute path with no success "http://www.mywebsite.com/images/plaid.jpg" It shows the image if I put it into the browser, but it doesnt show that image as the background when i use the absolute path for the location of my background image.

Comment: @codeyb : then I suspect that there is a preceding AND not properly closed css declaration ... so this one is never rendered **[like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/sc3MN/)** ... try running a css validation tool http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://mysite.com

Comment: I do appreciate your persistent help, this is my entire .css file. body { 
    background-image: url("http://www.mywebsite.com/images/plaid.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
} it is adding a semi colon in the middle there right after the quotations end, but it doesnt exist  i checked it multiple times to be sure.

Comment: @codeyb why you don't share a link to your css file? otherwise we can keep guessing what's wrong for a month ;)

Answer (score 4):

**Most important**

Keep in mind that relative URLs are resolved from the URL of your stylesheet.

So it will work if folder `images` is inside the `stylesheets` folder.

From you description you would need to change it to either

```
url("../images/plaid.jpg")
```

or

```
url("/images/plaid.jpg")
```

---

**Additional 1**

Also you cannot have no selector..

CSS is applied through selectors..

---

**Additional 2**

You should use either the shorthand `background` to pass multiple values like this

```
background: url("../images/plaid.jpg") no-repeat;
```

or the verbose syntax of specifying each property on its own

```
background-image: url("../images/plaid.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Comment: changed to this and it still didnt work body {
    background-image: url("/images/plaid.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Comment: also I use selectors I just didnt include any because I used 15-20 and it wouldnt be important to write out all the variations. body or html should work as a selector in its most general form but I dont know how it knows what their dimensions are. I also put the plaid.jpg file inside of my stylesheets folder and changed the path to /stylesheets/plaid.jpg and it didnt work either. it wouldnt let me edit my previous post

Comment: @codeyb when you give an exceptionally incomplete sample, everyone is going to expect the worst (especially when you say *no selector*).  We need enough to know you're not doing it completely wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If that really is all that's in your CSS file, then yes, nothing will happen. You need a selector, even if it's as simple as `body`:

```
body {
    background-image: url(...);
}
```

Comment: I stated thats what was in my css file minus the selector, I used every selector possible.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
body
{ 
    background:url("images/plaid.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
}
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9Zfa/

Answer (score 1):

You may debug using two ways:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to view page Source . Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find "mystyles.css" in source .
   click on mystyles.css link and check if it is not showing "404 not found".
2. You can INSPECT ELEMENT IN FIRBUG and set path to Image ,Set Image height and width because sometimes image doesnt show up.

Hope this may works !!.

Comment: I tried the first technique first and foremost, how do i set the img height and width so that .css will accept it? I've tried editing it in photoshop cs6.

Comment: first technique is to debug whether your mystyles.css is included or not with correct path.
you must try second technique which is fast. You can  set path to Image ,Set Image height and width in frebug.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
    background: url(images/Untitled-2.fw.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
background-size: cover;
    </style>
```