# Bootstrap Carousel Background Image Doesn't Show

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Carousel is sliding and showing the text in it but it doesnt show the background image.When i try to add image directly into it it shows the image but i want it to be background image. Here is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = ">

<title> My Portfolio </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride = "carousel">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target = "#theCarousel" data-slide-to = "0" class="active">
</li>
    <li data-target = "#theCarousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>

</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active sl1">

    <p>
        Text
    </p>
</div>

<div class="item sl2">

    <p>
        Text
    </p>
</div>

</div>

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide= "prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide= "next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</div>

</body>

</html>

<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src = 
"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
```

CSS File:

```
.sl1 {
  background-image : url(img/sl1.png) top center no-repeat;;
}

.sl2 {
  background-image: url(img/sl2.png) top center no-repeat;

}
```

I think i am doing something wrong about css but i'm not sure what.

Comment: Is image path correct ?

Comment: Can you also share a codepen ?

Comment: yes it is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't.

Comment: Try this - it seems to maybe be a duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945089/background-image-urlimages-plaid-jpg-no-repeat-wont-show-up

Comment: Did you try inspecting the CSS in browser tools ? Is the image loaded ?

Comment: or background: url(img/sl1.png) top center no-repeat; - and remove the extra semicolon and extra space before the colon.

Comment: @adpro it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `background-image` property.

Use `background` instead.

```
.sl1 {
  background: url(img/sl1.png) top center no-repeat;;
}

.sl2 {
  background: url(img/sl2.png) top center no-repeat;

}
```

Comment: So you div with class sl1 and sl2 has size defined ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using just background instead. You can use background-image, but you would need to specify everything else after.  See [background-image: url("images/plaid.jpg") no-repeat; wont show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945089/background-image-urlimages-plaid-jpg-no-repeat-wont-show-up) for more information.

```
.sl1 {
  background: url("img/sl1.png") top center no-repeat;
}

.sl2 {
  background: url("img/sl2.png") top center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I get it working.I put the img folder into the css folder and it worked.When i added the image directly with the same path it worked.But i think it works different with url.

Comment: That is what was suggested in first comment perhaps. Path issues.
Also `background-image` property will not take multiple values.

Comment: Yes, it was.  I believe you should be able to turn their comment into an answer. However, are you using just background: or your background-image?  One of my edited answers suggested using a fully qualified path for the image.  It was also suggested that you inspect to see if the image is actually loading. Give credit where credit is due.

Comment: @rach8garg, I would suggest adding the image path suggestion to your answer.  vignerd, accept his/her answer after, as the suggestion for the path was made by him/her to begin with, and background-image is not correct either.

Comment: Thank you @adpro for being a proponent of my efforts.